# How to add subtitle on a new line with exsheets

Tags: exsheets

I am using exsheets to create exercises. This package has the option to add a subtitle to a set of questions. My question is, I can't figure out how to put the subtitle on its own line. The screenshot shows the subtitle "Simplify etc" on the same line as the exercise title. I would like the subtitle on a separate line underneath the  Practice Exercises title. I've looked through the manual but couldn't find anything obvious. I am currently using the following latex code:

```
 \SetupExSheets{
   headings = block-subtitle
 }

 \begin{question}[subtitle=Simplify the following expressions,subtitle-format=\normalsize]
  \begin{tasks}(4)
   \task $3x^2 + 2x^2$
   \task $x^2 x^3$
   \task $p^5 p^3$
   \task $7 a^3 3 a$
   \task $10 n^2 2 m^5$
   \task $u^0 v^5$
   \task $x^0 x^4$
   \task $a^6/a^2$
  \end{tasks}
\end{question}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code to your preamble:

```
\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{block-subtitle}{default}{
    join = {
        title[r,B]number[l,B](.333em,0pt) ;
        title[l,b]subtitle[l,t](0pt,0pt) % join subtitle to title (x offset, y  offset)
    } ,
    attach = {
        main[l,vc]title[l,vc](0pt,0pt) ;
        main[r,vc]points[l,vc](\marginparsep,0pt)
    }
}
```

[image: A]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}

 \SetupExSheets{
    headings = block-subtitle
}

%*********************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<
\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{block-subtitle}{default}{
    join = {
        title[r,B]number[l,B](.333em,0pt) ;
        title[l,b]subtitle[l,t](0pt,0pt) % join subtitle to title (x offset, y  offset)
    } ,
    attach = {
        main[l,vc]title[l,vc](0pt,0pt) ;
        main[r,vc]points[l,vc](\marginparsep,0pt)
    }
}
%***********************************

\begin{document}    

\begin{question}[subtitle=Simplify the following expressions:,subtitle-format=\normalsize]
    \begin{tasks}(4)
        \task $3x^2 + 2x^2$
        \task $x^2 x^3$
        \task $p^5 p^3$
        \task $7 a^3 3 a$
        \task $10 n^2 2 m^5$
        \task $u^0 v^5$
        \task $x^0 x^4$
        \task $a^6/a^2$
    \end{tasks}
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

The  `title[l,b]subtitle[l,t](0pt,0pt)`  means join the left-bottom corner of the box `title` with the left-top corner of the box  `subtitle` with an x-offset of 0pt and y-offset of 0pt.